# Need explanation of java class constructor for tree

Tags: java, tree, nodes

In an algorithm question, the description says following:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
```

My question 1: It is hard to understand what is `TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }` please explain what this line means. Why is this necessary.

My question 2: how to put `TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }` into actual code of constructor? this is what I try so far but gets error:

```
  TreeNode (int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right, TreeNode x){
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
    this.x = { val = x; }
    this.val = val;
  }
}
```

Error: illegal start of expression at line `this.x = { val = x; }`

Comment: this's pretty standard java stuff. Learn the basic first before diving to the datastructure/algorithm

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept. And I also agree: this is basic stuff. And normally I would have only commented, but I needed the space to get down the core points.

Comment: @GhostCat I agree. I got confused and thought that line is field type and field name too. And struggled to get out of that confusion. But it's great that you understood immediately where my thoughts was off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be blinded by formatting. The first constructor shouldn't be in the comment. Instead, your class could look like this:

```
public class TreeNode {
  int val;
  TreeNode left;
  TreeNode right;

  TreeNode(int x) { 
    val = x; 
  }

TreeNode (int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right){
  this.left = left;
  this.right = right;
  this.val = val;
}
```

Constructors parameters are typically assigned to fields of your class. And you simply confused (yourself), by assuming that you need that `{ val = x }` snippet again. But that snipped is just the complete body of the first constructor.

And just to be precise, actually you would rather do something like

```
  TreeNode(int x) { 
    this(x, null, null); 
  }
```

In other words: when you create your *first* node, then you only need a value, its left/right child nodes are null at this point. So instead of having two different constructor bodies, the first constructor simply invokes the second constructor (to avoid code duplication).

Comment: thanks! this answers my question. But got one question for your post, you mean I do not need second constructor and only first constructor can take care of creating first node with left and right being null and also adding left/right node to that first node?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.